# Uncaught Error: ERROR: ... could not locate ZeroClipboard JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, zclip

I am trying to use zclip.js.

if I use external file "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf", it's fine.

```
$("#face").zclip({
    path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: $("#face").text(),
    afterCopy:function(){}
});
```

if I use:

```
path: "ZeroClipboard.swf"
```

the code will throw an error:

> Uncaught Error: ERROR: ZeroClipboard SWF could not locate
>   ZeroClipboard JS object! Expected element ID:
>   global-zeroclipboard-flash-bridge

**Full version of the code can be found here: http://to-0.bl.ee/face/k2.html, starts from**

> $("#face"+i).zclip({

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you must download this version with all packages and your zClip function will work:
Current Release [jquery.zclip.1.1.1.zip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/archive/jquery.zclip.1.1.1.zip) ~8KB